# How can I get the maximum length of a DAC field without using fieldname.Length?

Tags: acumatica

I have a client request to match an SOOrder.ShipTermsID value to a "matching" SOOrder.ShipVia value when the SOOrder.ShipVia is selected for the SO record ("matching" here means the IDs are identical as much as they can be). They want these fields to always correspond. So I started with the below in my SOOrderEntry extension:

```
\\other using statements
using PX.Objects.CS;

namespace PX.Objects.SO
{
    public class SOOrderEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<SOOrderEntry>
    {
        protected virtual void _(Events.FieldUpdated<SOOrder, SOOrder.shipVia> e)
        {
            if (e.Row == null || e.Row.ShipVia == null) return;
            ShipTerms term = PXSelectReadonly<ShipTerms,
                Where<ShipTerms.shipTermsID, Equal<Required<ShipTerms.shipTermsID>>>>
                .Select(Base, e.Row.ShipVia);
            e.Row.ShipTermsID = term?.ShipTermsID;
        }
    }
}
```

However, the SOOrder.ShipVia and SOOrder.ShipTermsID fields do not have the same length. They are nvarchar(15) and nvarchar(10), respectively, in both the DB and the DAC declarations.

OK fine, so I need to truncate the value from the ShipVia to the same length of the ShipTermsID. BUT, in case this value were to ever change in Acumatica, I want to write my code so it doesn't rely on a hard-coded value. So, my next thought was to do the following:

```
    protected virtual void _(Events.FieldUpdated<SOOrder, SOOrder.shipVia> e)
    {
        if (e.Row == null || e.Row.ShipVia == null) return;
        ShipTerms term = PXSelectReadonly<ShipTerms,
            Where<ShipTerms.shipTermsID, Equal<Required<ShipTerms.shipTermsID>>>>
            .Select(Base, e.Row.ShipVia.Substring(0, e.Row.ShipTermsID.Length));
        e.Row.ShipTermsID = term?.ShipTermsID;
    }
```

But this fails because the e.Row.ShipTermsID value is NULL at this point, so the Length comes back NULL and the screen throws an exception.

I've found tons of info online about how to get DB Schema info but everything I've found seems to want me to open a new DB connection string. I'm not sure that's the best approach here and I'm concerned about potential performance issues. Besides, in the event that the DAC field is ever shorter than the DB field, the Schema info wouldn't be helpful anyway, so I need the DAC field length.

If I ultimately need to just use a constant for this, I can, but I'd like to avoid that to save myself the trouble in the future, and if not for this particular field, then at least I will know for next time.

How can I retrieve the maximum length of a DAC field from a without using fieldname.Length?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from Acumatica 2018R2 version there is also another way to do the same thing or even **adjust** any attribute property using `PXCache.Adjust` method. This way is approved by the Acumatica platform team and it is better than `PXCache.GetAttributesReadOnly` due to a higher code level.

```
protected virtual void _(Events.FieldUpdated<SOOrder, SOOrder.shipVia> e)
{
    if (e.Row == null || e.Row.ShipVia == null) return;

    int length = 0;
    e.Cache.Graph.Caches[typeof(ShipTerms)]
        .Adjust<PXDBStringAttribute>()
        .For<ShipTerms.shipTermsID>(attr => length = attr?.Length ?? 0);

    ShipTerms term = PXSelectReadonly<ShipTerms,
        Where<ShipTerms.shipTermsID, Equal<Required<ShipTerms.shipTermsID>>>>
        .Select(Base, e.Row.ShipVia.Substring(0, Math.Min(e.Row.ShipVia.Length, length)));
    e.Row.ShipTermsID = term?.ShipTermsID;
}
```

Comment: I had occasion to revisit this project and I updated my code to this version. It works great!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your question, I glad to see you are trying to do it properly, instead of hardcoded constant value. You can easily get all the information you need from the field attributes using `PXCache.GetAttributesReadonly` method.
In your case just do the following:

```
protected virtual void _(Events.FieldUpdated<SOOrder, SOOrder.shipVia> e)
{
    if (e.Row == null || e.Row.ShipVia == null) return;

    int lenght = e.Cache.Graph.Caches[typeof(ShipTerms)]
        .GetAttributesReadonly<ShipTerms.shipTermsID>()
        .OfType<PXDBStringAttribute>()
        .FirstOrDefault()?.Length ?? 0;

    ShipTerms term = PXSelectReadonly<ShipTerms,
        Where<ShipTerms.shipTermsID, Equal<Required<ShipTerms.shipTermsID>>>>
        .Select(Base, e.Row.ShipVia.Substring(0, Math.Min(e.Row.ShipVia.Length, length)));
    e.Row.ShipTermsID = term?.ShipTermsID;
}
```

Comment: I had to make one change to your code: `e.Row.ShipVia.Substring(0, Math.Min(e.Row.ShipVia.Length, length))` otherwise I would get an error if the ShipVia.Length was shorter than the ShipTermsID maximum length. Otherwise, this was precisely what I needed. Thanks for the helpful and prompt response!